# Question Tag problem!

Tags: question-tags

Question:

> A man like you should not do this, _______?

Which question tag should I use in the blank space?

1. should he?
2. should you?

Which would be grammatically correct? I think 1 is true.

Comment: I'm inclined to say "A man like you should not do this, should they?", but I'm not sure

Comment: "Bob, you shouldn't be doing this."

Answer (score 5):

When speaking to Bob, Alice is not talking about **him.** She's talking about a man **like** Bob. A general man, who happens to be like Bob. So it's *should he*.

> Bob, a man like you shouldn't do this, should he?

The general statement and its impersonal tag question is not a personal criticism; it's a hedged criticism, a criticism by analogy, a gentle prod in the right direction.

Using *should you?* as the tag question turns what should be a general statement, "A man like you shouldn't do this" into a specific statement which is directly aimed at Bob: "should you?" It becomes pointed, a personal criticism.

Comment: Now I read this interpretation, I agree with it more than my original answer. A hypothetical man like-Bob? *He* is a third person.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: seeing Andrew Leach's answer, and ScotM's comments, their replies are better. Consider this wrong, but left for completeness].

Alice speaks to Bob: *"Bob, a man like you should not do this, should you?"* (Talking to Bob as the second-person)

Alice speaks to Claire: *"Claire, a man like Bob should not do this, should he?"* (Talking *about* Bob as the third-person).

Alice starts by speaking to Bob: *"Bob, a man like you should not do this"*, Alice pauses and turns to address Claire: "*should he?"*. (Changing who is second-person and third-person part way through).

In the sentence you've asked, "a man like you" most likely goes with "should you".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You

Comment: This answer imposes meaning on the sentence that is not required. The expression could introduce an emotional distance to soften a suggested moral judgement, so Bob feels like I'm talking about another man in comparison to Bob, even if I am talking about Bob. *A man like you should not do this, should he?* Also, it may be my intent to compare qualities and actions without imposing any judgement on Bob. My 12 year old son is struggling to get into the back seat of a Fiat 500: *A man like you [6'6" tall] should not do this [climb into the back seat of a Fiat 500], should he?*